# Disable Common Tab in VB.NET Intellisense

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, intellisense

When working in a VB.NET project in Visual Studio (2008 specifically, but hopefully the answer applies to any version) is it possible to have intellisense/auto-complete only show the "All" tab instead of the "Common"/"All" tab?  Or alternatively, have it default to the "All" tab.

Being predominately a C# developer having the editor try to be smarter than me by telling me what it thinks I should be looking for is more of an annoyance than anything.

NOTE: I do have ReSharper and DevExpress installed, so if the solution only works with one of those tools it is available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am afraid I don't know of a way to default to the All tab. I have grown accustomed to using keyboard shortcuts to toggle between the two, to a degree where it doesn't bother me anymore.

I know its not what you are looking for, but maybe it can help you anyway :)

`[ALT]`+`[.]` Go to All tab

`[ALT]`+`[,]` Go to Common tab

Comment: Not the solution I was hoping for, but a decent work around.  Muscle memory quickly kicks in anyways.